# How to remove autocomplete from input?

Tags: autocomplete, twitter-typeahead

I have tried autocomplete="off", autocomplete="none" , autocomplete="/" ,autocomplete="new-text"
but still it shows autocomplete

browser autocomplete overlaps typehead autocomplete popup

I don't Know how to remove this autocomplete

Thank you in advance!!

```html
<form name="clientForm" class="kt-form kt-form--label-right" novalidate role="form" autocomplete="new-text">
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 typeahead">
                        <label for="country">Country <span style="color:red">*</span></label><br />
                        
                        <input id="add-c-country" class="form-control" name="country" type="text" dir="ltr" placeholder="Enter Country" autocomplete="new-text" />

                        <div class="form-text text-muted" ng-show="clientForm.country.$touched || clientForm.$submitted"
                             ng-messages="clientForm.country.$error" role="alert">
                            <div class="req-red" ng-message="required">Please Select Country</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

I am using typeahead.js for auto complete

```js
function applyAutocomplete(id, array,namE) {
            $('input#' + id).typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
                accent: true,
                offset: true
            }, {
                name: namE,
                limit: 100,
                source: substringMatcher(array)
            });
        }
        
        
        
        applyAutocomplete('add-c-country', $ctrl.countryNameList,'country');
```

[image]

Comment: did you meant your typehead autocomplete overlaps by browser autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try just completely removing the autocomplete parameter?

Like this:

```
<input id="add-c-country" class="form-control" name="country" type="text" dir="ltr" placeholder="Enter Country" />
```

Edit after reading your edited question:

You can not disable browser autocomplete in your own code. That is a browser specific setting.
For chrome you can do the following:

> 1. Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three lines at the top right of the screen.)
> 2. Click on Settings.
> 3. At the bottom of the page, click 'Show advanced Settings'
> 4. In the Passwords and Forms section, uncheck 'Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click'.

Hope this solves your problem.

Best regards.

Comment: yes but then it will automatically take browser auto complete

Comment: To my knowledge you can not disable browser autocomplete in your own code. That is a browser specific setting. For chrome you can do the following: 1. Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three lines at the top right of the screen.)
2. Click on Settings.
3. At the bottom of the page, click 'Show advanced Settings'
4. In the Passwords and Forms section, uncheck 'Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click'.